# buildx is not a docker command

Tags: docker

I've got Docker 20.10.21 installed on Ubuntu 23.04.  I've also run

```sh
export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
```

However, when I run `docker buildx`, I get

```
docker: 'buildx' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

I was under the impression that, on Debian-flavored OSes, buildx comes installed with the `docker.io` package.  How do I get this working?

`docker version` shows

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.20.1
 Git commit:        20.10.21-0ubuntu3
 Built:             Tue Feb 28 14:28:22 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.1
  Git commit:       20.10.21-0ubuntu3
  Built:            Tue Feb 28 12:17:52 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.12-0ubuntu3
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4-0ubuntu3
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

Comment: @DanielW.how did you install Docker to begin with?  From their repos or from snaps?  Or, did you install directly from the Ubuntu repos (which have very outdated versions of Docker)  The answer to this will be important.

Comment: I ran `apt -y install docker.io`.

Comment: that is an ancient version of docker, and because you don't have the Docker repositories set up on your system you **will not** have a recent version of Docker and other plugin libraries.  Follow the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ for setting up *their* repos for you to get the properly up to date version of Docker and its plugins, then the answers provided by the other users will work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this worked previously on 23.04 (I have the image to prove it), but is now broken (I assume due to an update).

Comment: I'm unsure about the specific `docker buildx` command, but I think that some buildx-related functionality is removed in the upgrade from '20.10.21' to '24.0.x'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're encountering the issue with Docker BuildKit and need to install `docker-buildx`, you can use the following command:

```sh
sudo apt install docker-buildx
```

Comment: Only this is the correct answer to Daniel W.'s OP, done by `apt install docker.io`, because, as hep put, apt doesn't see any package named docker-buildx-plugin

Comment: I had to do `wsl --shutdown` & only then it worked the next time i tried `docker build . -t node-app` otherwise i was confused why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you follow the steps described here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ and you should be able to install the docker-buildx-plugin

```
    $ apt-cache policy docker-buildx-plugin
docker-buildx-plugin:
  Installed: 0.10.4-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal
  Candidate: 0.10.4-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal
  Version table:
 *** 0.10.4-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.10.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

The `docker-buildx-plugin` package is generally not installed by default. That said, let's check to make sure it's there and, if it's not, get it installed. Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Check to see if the plugin is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt list --installed | grep buildx
   ```

   If the above command returns nothing, then we've confirmed that the `docker-buildx-plugin` package is not installed. Continue to the next step.
2. Install the missing package:

   ```
   sudo apt install docker-buildx-plugin
   ```
3. Try your `docker buildx` command again

One thing that I've seen is that an upgrade from one version of Ubuntu to another can also result in this plugin disappearing from Docker's view. Reinstalling just this plugin alone resolves the matter.

Comment: `apt` doesn't see any package named `docker-buildx-plugin`.  `apt search buildx` also shows nothing.

Comment: @DanielW. You have to install docker from their repository: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
After that, `docker-buildx-plugin` will appearch in the search.